# Store and retrieve selection elements in Google Apps Script via PropertiesService

Tags: google-apps-script, element, google-docs

The goal is to store the selected text into PropertiesService for later insertion into a Google Doc. Kind of like cut and paste so that the user can collapse and expand elements.

The code is

```
ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
ui.alert(JSON.stringify(selection))
```

The alert contents is

```
[{}]
```

I understand that selection returns a `Range`. So I tried to store individual elements:

```
if (selection) {
  var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    ui.alert(JSON.stringify(element.getElement()))
  }
}
```

The alert contents for individual elements is always

```
[{}]
```

where there is one `{}` for every element in the list.

The functions I plan to use to store and retrieve follow:

```
function save_value(elements) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('selection', JSON.stringify(elements));
}

function get_value() {
  return JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('selection'));
}
```

I realize there is a workaround here by storing the element values.

```
element.getElement().asText().getText();
```

This comes with downsides.

1. Code complexity when elements are partially selected. If the selection is partially selecting an element, it creates complexity in the code. The code would have to leverage `isPartial()`, `getStartOffset()` and `getEndOffsetInclusive()`.
2. Code complexity in multiple elements. Instead of one swift store, I have to iterate and chain each store, or have multiple stores, or something else.
3. Unsure about this one but code complexity in distinct elements. Based on the element, the value method varies. For example, storing an image vs text.

Note, I also realized that [not all elements can be inserted](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs), and am experimenting to see if there is a workaround by using elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, "PropertiesService" cannot directly save the image and object. So I think that it is required to think of the workaround for achieving your goal. For this, can I ask you about your goal? About "cut and paste" you are thinking, is only one object saved?

Comment: Ugh, thanks. The goal is to collapse and expand elements in Google Docs.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't image about `to collapse and expand elements in Google Docs`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: As a workaround you can store the selection in a dummy document - this will allow you to store elements that cannot be stored in PropertiesService. However, you will still need to iterate through all elements, find out the element type and append accordingly to the dummy document.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka that is a solution. Unfortunately, it would create the problem of storing these documents without filling up the user's drive with meaningless docs. If you think of the number of collapses a user may have in a document, it could be tens of docs. While I could create a "special" directory to hide all these in, I was hoping that using the proper solution, PropertiesService, can resolve this. I believe it can, I just have to stringify all elements based on element type.

Comment: Sure. Just be aware that if you try to stringify an image, the resulting string might be too large too be stored as a script property.